# How to define a component class as an interface field in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have the following interface:

```
interface Drawer {
  title: string,
  content: Component
}
```

Afterwards I instantiate this interface:

```
let workspace: Drawer = {
    title: 'Workspaces',
    content: SidebarWorkspacesComponent
};
```

During compilation I get the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/sidebar/sidebar-toggler.component.ts(36,4): error TS2559: Type 'typeof SidebarWorkspacesComponent' has no properties in common with type 'Component'.
```

Now I tried using ComponentRef and read dozens of articles but can't figure out how to pass a component in an interface. Obviously I could simply declare content as "any" but I would rather know how to do things properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The closest thing that you can get without further deps. is `content: Type<any>` using [Type from @angular/core](https://angular.io/api/core/Type), as components dont really share a common interface, unless you enforce it.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo you should make that an answer

Comment: @PierreDuc done, hope it helps

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, any comments about my implementation?

Comment: @SiddAjmera essentially it matches the placeholder interface approach that I describe in my answer. Its a solution, but IMO adds no value as its an empty interface.

Comment: Just added a comment for that. Thanks a lot for your inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can create an `interface` and then specify the type of `content` in the `Drawer` interface as that type. Something like this:

Here's that generic interface:

```
export interface GenericComponent {
  /*Your Specification Here*/
}
```

Then in your `Drawer` interface:

```
interface Drawer {
  title: string,
  content: GenericComponent
}
```

Now, you can assign any component that has implemented the `GenericComponent` interface on it to the Drawer interface's `content`.

So once you implement this `GenericComponent` interface on the SidebarWorkspacesComponent`, you can then specify the type of`Drawer`'s content to it.

---

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-generic-interface-for-assigning-component-as-types?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: I feel like it's the best approach for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @DannyCoulombe, awesome. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

The closest would be to make your interface generic and change it to:

```
interface Drawer<T = any> {
  title: string,
  content: Type<T>
}
```

Using the [`Type<T>` interface from @angular/core](https://angular.io/api/core/Type), as components dont really share a common interface, unless you enforce it by implementing a sort of placeholder interface.

An example of the previous approach is the [dialog API from material](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/dialog/dialog.ts#L127), as it uses a similar interface in order to take component types as arguments.